# Jordan normal form powers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

> Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ such that $A=PBP^{-1}$ where $B$ is in Jordan normal form with $\lambda_i(k)_j$ Where $i$ is the size, $k$ is the eigenvalue and $j$ the order.

If $A$ was diagonal($i=1$) then $A^n$ in Jordan form has $\lambda_1(k^n)_j$.
If the Jordan form has Jordan blocks bigger then 1, how do we find $A^n$ In Jordan form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Jordon block of size $i$ and eigenvalue $k$ has the form $(kI+t)$ where $t^i=0$. Thus $(kI+t)^n$ will just be the truncated binomial expansion:$$\sum_{r=0}^{i-1} {n \choose r} k^{n-r}t^r$$

Comment: Can you explain why we can treat each Jordan block on his own? Aren’t they all a part of one matrix?

Comment: Also, $t$ is a very specific matrix, is there a nice expression or pattern to its powers?

Comment: The non-zero entries of $t^i$ will be the diagonal row of $1$'s starting at $(1,1+i)$ and moving down and right.

Comment: If I got you, does it mean it will always be an upper diagonal matrix?

Comment: Yes.  To answer you first question, when you multiply a row by a column, the non-zero entries on the row will never overlap with entries on the column belonging to a different block.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I understand.

Comment: But they are no longer in Jordan normal form, is there a nice way to get them to it?

Comment: As you pointed out, the matrix will be upper triangular, so conjugate to a matrix in Jordan normal form.  I don't know of any simple formula for it though.

Comment: I continue this in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3762073/jordan-normal-form-of-powers-of-powers-of-jordan-normal-form

Comment: That is a good idea.